# Unable to install pip package while building docker file

Tags: python, docker, pip, dockerfile

I am having similar issue when building my docker file. In my case I am trying to install `aiohttp==3.6.2` and on `Python 3.6.8`. I have other packages listed in my docker file which are successfully installed.

Command in Docker File to install the package. (Base OS Image - `Ubuntu 18.04`) `RUN pip3 install aiohttp==3.6.2`

Just to add, I am able successfully install on my machine's environment using `pip install aiohttp==3.6.2`

Anyone can help?

Edit - More information

```
Step 6/15 : RUN pip3 install aiohttp==3.6.2
 ---> Running in 9b36f2b7bd80
Collecting aiohttp==3.6.2
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /packages/7c/39/7eb5f98d24904e0f6d3edb505d4aa60e3ef83c0a58d6fe18244a51757247/aiohttp-3.6.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /packages/7c/39/7eb5f98d24904e0f6d3edb505d4aa60e3ef83c0a58d6fe18244a51757247/aiohttp-3.6.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /packages/7c/39/7eb5f98d24904e0f6d3edb505d4aa60e3ef83c0a58d6fe18244a51757247/aiohttp-3.6.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /packages/7c/39/7eb5f98d24904e0f6d3edb505d4aa60e3ef83c0a58d6fe18244a51757247/aiohttp-3.6.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /packages/7c/39/7eb5f98d24904e0f6d3edb505d4aa60e3ef83c0a58d6fe18244a51757247/aiohttp-3.6.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/7c/39/7eb5f98d24904e0f6d3edb505d4aa60e3ef83c0a58d6fe18244a51757247/aiohttp-3.6.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))
```

I also tried to manually install that package by bashing into my running container. It threw out same error :

**Error**
[image: Bash error]

**My Docker file**
[image: Docker]

Comment: I'm able to successfully `RUN pip3 install aiohttp==3.6.2` in a Dockerfile based on `ubuntu:18.04`. Whatever your problem is, you'll need to provide us with more information if we're going to be able to help you. Please update your question to include your actual Dockerfile and the specific error message you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I have added the logs. Please see to it. If there is anything else I need to put out please tell. @larsks

Comment: not an answer, but you should install multiple packages with `pip` in one command: `pip3 install numpy requests pandas ....`

Comment: Installing on different line allowed me to see which package exactly is the issue as if it was one line, it will always say its the first package as the whole command failed.

Answer (score 0):

Following trail of many questions-answers to same topic. I found this helped me to install the package

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package-name>
```